# Shaking off verbosity from python + selenium script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to parse different track names from a webpage. My script is working just fine. I've used try n break in the print statement to get the desired results. Is there any one liner print statement to avoid try-break expression? Finally, I've used the same selector twice in my script- one for finding location and the other for selecting the same. Is it possible I can shake off this redundancy?

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.shazam.com/charts/top-100/united-states")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.grid-vert-center"))) # This selector and the following one are identical so I wished to shake off the verbosity by using once
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.grid-vert-center"):
    try:
        track = item.find_element_by_css_selector('div.title a.ellip').text
    except Exception:
        track = ""
    print(track)  

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the lines number you can replace

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.grid-vert-center"))) # This selector and the following one are identical so I wished to shake off the verbosity by using once
for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.grid-vert-center"):
```

with

```
for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.grid-vert-center"))):
```

as `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located` returns you a list which you can use for iteration.

As for `try`/`except`... You can use below instead

```
tracks = [track for track in item.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.title a.ellip')]
if tracks:
    print(tracks[0].text)
```

P.S. Note that if your code works well, but you're searching for some improvements, you should use [`Code Review`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your answer. My main concern was to have any workaround regarding not to use the same thing more than once in my script which i did above. Your solution is what i was after. Thanks again.